Weakly, but not strongly convergent sequence in $(C([0,1]),||\cdot||_{\infty})$
I'm looking for a sequence $(f_n)_n$ and some $f$ in $C([0,1])$ such that $f_n\rightharpoonup f$, but $||f-f_n||_{\infty}\nrightarrow 0$.
I know that $f_n\rightharpoonup f$ is equivalent to $f_n\to f$ pointwise and $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}||f_n||<\infty$.
What I tried/found out: The monomials don't work because their pointwise limit $1_{\{1\}}$ is not continuous. I also realized that the $f_n$ must not be equicontinuous. This makes it seem like they have to get steeper and steeper but this somewhat goes against my intuition of their pointwise limit being continuous.

Never mind, I just found an example: One can choose continuous functions $f_n$ such that $f_n(\frac{1}{n})=1, \text{supp}f_n\subseteq[\frac{1}{2n},\frac{3}{2n}],||f_n||=1$. Then they are uniformly bounded and pointwise convergent to $0$, but not strongly convergent.
